# dynamically populated select does not let to select the options

Tags: jquery

i dynamically populate the select using jquery $ajax but when i select the value, it reloads again, looks like it keeps re-populating whenever i click, but the options gets selected when i add a "alert(this.value)". can anyone help me understand what i am missing?

added the snippet of code here :

```
....
$("select#TASSIGNED").change(function(){
$("select#TASSIGNED option[value=28]").prop("selected", true).end().change();
      });
....


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: profilesAction ,
    async: false,
        datatype: "json",
        data: {'SELECT' : 1 },
    success: function(request) {
      $("select#TASSIGNED").html("<option></option>");          

      $.each(eval(request), function(i,item){
        $("select#TASSIGNED").append("<option value="+item.CID+">"+ item.second + " - " + item.third +"</option>");
        });
      }
    });           


html code:
      <select name='TASSIGNED' class='form-control' id='TASSIGNED'>
  <option>1
  <option>2
  </select>
```

In the above example, i hardcoded value=28 to see if that gets selected but it did n't.

$.ajax populates the select options successfully onclick of the tab href(not shown here but that part of the code works great), so when i proceed to select an option it reloads again though i see it gets selected when i "alert" it. I want that value to be shown as "SELECTED" rather than the values getting repopulated again.

I went through several questions in SO but nothing really helped. 
I tried the prop instead of attr but that did not help either.

I'm using 1.9, tested with firefox and safari, it did not work with either of attr or prop.

Generally how is this done , can anyone give me a sample ? thanks for the help.

Comment: You might want to show some of your code and the DOM and which element exactly is getting replaced or populated.

Comment: added now. hope it helps. i thought this was more a generic requirement. I am a newbie in jQuery , thought this is trivial for which i am breaking my head :)

Comment: Can you post the whole code on how ajax is posted as well. Otherwise it would make no sense

Comment: u talking about the backend code that retrieves the data from database ? it pulls all the values from the table and return as json_encode($return_arr); nothing much.

Comment: I meant when and how is the `AJAX` request made. Does it fire when a event is triggered..?

Comment: I ran into an issue like this using regular JS. Instead of editing the HTML, you have to edit the DOM. I got an ugly review because I write ugly code, but this might point you in the right direction: [JS Select Boxes](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28988)

Comment: AJAX request is made when the href is clicked like      $("#accordion2").click(function() { $ajax .... });

Comment: No responses or nobody has tried this before ?